# How to disable a field in Ant Design React Form?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using React with **Ant Design** and I want to disable one Form.Item **username** field. Please see my sample code below,

```
<Form.Item disabled style={{ padding: '0px 20px' }}>
    {getFieldDecorator('username', {
        initialValue: this.state.userInfo.username,
        validate: [
            {
                trigger: ['onChange', 'onBlur'],
                rules: [
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: t('pleaseInput.username'),
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    })
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to display some sort of UI component inside your `<Form.Item>`.

I suppose you want to display an `<Input>` since you have a username. Here's what could be possible with your code :

```
<Form.Item disabled style={{ padding: '0px 20px' }}>
    {getFieldDecorator('username', {
        initialValue: this.state.userInfo.username,
        validate: [
            {
                trigger: ['onChange', 'onBlur'],
                rules: [
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: t('pleaseInput.username'),
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    })(
        <Input
         // This is where you want to disable your UI control
         disabled={true}
         placeholder="Username"
        />
      )}
</Form.Item>
```

**Edit 2021:** this answer targets the use of ant design's v3 Form component. While the boolean to disable a field might be the same, the Form component in the v4 has seen a lot of changes. See the documentation to migrate from v3 to v4 [here](https://ant.design/components/form/v3).